# How to return to the previous screen when Bluetooth connection is lost?

Tags: android, bluetooth

At first, my android device scans for bluetooth devices and then displays them in a listview. I select one of them and a new screen appears. How to return to the main screen when the connection is lost. Following is the code for selected device screen.

```
public class devicefound extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private OutputStream outStream = null;
Button b1;
private static final UUID MY_UUID = 
        UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
public static String address;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    findViewById(R.id.b1).setOnClickListener(this);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    String address = getIntent().getStringExtra("address");
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    try {
        btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    } catch (IOException e) { }

    run();

}

public void run(){
    try {
        btSocket.connect();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {  }
        return;
    }
}


public void onClick(View v){
    String message1 = "1";

    byte[] msgBuffer1 = message1.getBytes();
    try{
    outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e){ }
         try {
            outStream.write(msgBuffer1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

}           


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (outStream != null) {
        try {
            outStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}

}
```

Comment: well you may know this already, but I would start with monitoring the state of the BluetoothAdapter that you set in a service. From there you can, using the onBind, method to send a message back to the current activity to call onBackPressed(). I think this will definitely get you going in the right direction http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample :)

Answer (score 0):

As I know you should use BroadcastReceiver in a such situation.
Something like this http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/05/start-bluetooth-discoverable-and.html

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to continuously check the status of only the selected device (whose name and address I know) and that too in the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return to the previous screen, then you can call the [finish](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) method which your devicefound class inherits from Activity.